Jenkins doesn't receive correct code from sh script out of podman container
I have a Jenkins pipeline where I run tests in a container and the tests are triggered by .sh script.
There is an intermittent problem when script returns exit code 1, but some how Jenkins stage thinks it's code 0 and passes.
It happens in ~50% of time and feels like there is a race condition, but I can't figure out what exactly I need to change.
Jenkins pipeline code
script {

                def exitCode = sh(script: "podman run \
                        /path/tests.sh", label: "Running UI tests", returnStatus: true)

                echo "Exit code for tests: ${exitCode}"

                if(exitCode != 0) {
                  error("UI tests failed with exit code: ${exitCode}")
                }
        }

Sometimes it works just fine:

But sometimes not at all without any code changes:


My feeling is that could come from podman, perhaps problems with connecting to git or something like this. To see, whether tests.sh is being executed at all, and what it is actually doing (in case that tests.sh is the culprit), put  a set -x  into the script.

Based on your log output it seems that the two examples actually execute different code so it might be that your test framework and/or that sh script somehow changes the return code. Also, I've got several questions: 1) how comes that podman run /path/tests.sh actually works, is it the real command you execute? 2) Jenkins will fail the build automatically if a sh step returns a non-zero code. Why do you need to check for the exact value? 3) Why using podman command in a sh instead of using the Docker plugin?
